# How to use custom header and different layout, guards, and custom login in ABP?

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, abp

I checked in the ABP documentation Angular https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Quick-Start
they are providing their own layout.
In the app component.ts file they have added loader and dynamic layout components

```
<abp-loader-bar></abp-loader-bar>
 <abp-dynamic-layout></abp-dynamic-layout>
```

I don't want their dynamic layout component

I want to place a header, router outlet, and footer on the app component page.

Also their they implemented SSO login (Single Signon) currently I don't want an SSO login. I want normal login.

I checked they are provided an option of the replaceable components part using ReplaceableComponentsService from '@abp/ng.core'

[image: Here they have provided an option to replace logo component, in the middle menus and in the right add new options]

I am able to add a different component in that but then it's specific to the header only.

As in my project, I want a completely different header along with a sidebar and footer.

[image: Mine Custom Project View]

I can do this in normal Angular but in ABP they are providing their own layout also I haven't seen they have implemented guard, so how I checked on my end that the user is logged in normal Angular, I m creating guard and check in the guard if satisfies return true otherwise return false and navigating to auth pages.

Answer (score 1):

#### Replacing the Layout

I do not recommend removing the `abp-dynamic-layout`. If you remove this, the app may not work properly. Because the ABP packages use the dynamic-layout. You should replace the `ApplicationLayoutComponent` to achieve placing your own layout. For example:

Run the following command to create a component called `primary-layout` via Angular CLI:

```sh
ng generate component primary-layout
```

Open the generated `primary-layout.component.ts` file and replace the its content with the below content that I have prepared for you:

```
import { AuthService } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'abp-primary-layout',
  template: `
    <div
      style="
    width: calc(100vw - 200px);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 40px;
  "
      id="header"
    >
      <h5>HEADER</h5>
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex">
      <div
        style="width: 200px; background-color: #333; color: #fff; height: 100vh; padding: 10px"
        id="sidebar"
      >
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/identity/users"> Users </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/identity/roles"> Roles </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/tenant-management/tenants"> Tenants </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a (click)="login()"> Login </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-top: 50px; flex: 1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer
      style="
    width: calc(100vw - 200px);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 40px;
  "
    >
      <h5>FOOTER</h5>
    </footer>
  `,
})
export class PrimaryLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  login() {
    this.authService.initLogin();
  }
}
```

A new layout has created. Next, the `ApplicationLayoutComponent` from @abp/ng.theme.basic package should be replaced. See how to achieve this:

```
import { ReplaceableComponentsService } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { eThemeBasicComponents } from '@abp/ng.theme.basic';
import { PrimaryLayoutComponent } from './primary-layout/primary-layout.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <abp-loader-bar></abp-loader-bar>
    <abp-dynamic-layout></abp-dynamic-layout>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private replaceableComponent: ReplaceableComponentsService) {
    this.replaceableComponent.add({
      component: PrimaryLayoutComponent,
      key: eThemeBasicComponents.ApplicationLayout,
    });
  }
}
```

See the final UI:

[image: replacing the application layout]

#### SSO

As of 4.3, the both flow (resource owner password flow, authorization code flow) is available for Angular UI. For more information, see the v4.3 ABP blog post.

The ABP Angular UI uses the `angular-oauth2-oidc` package for the authentication. See the [Password Flow document](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/using-password-flow.html) on the package documentation to learn how to implement the password flow in Angular. You should also implement the password flow for the Identity Server.

Comment: Yes I checked I m able to implement that section in your style as well by removing their layout as well. working fine for both scenerios